# Unable to install foreman in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, foreman

I am trying to install foreman in ubuntu 12.04, After adding apt source and executing foreman-installer command giving me the below error.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/kafo/puppet_module_parser.rb:21:in `initialize': uninitialized constant Puppet::Parser::Parser (NameError)
```

Couldn't find much in google....

How to solve it??

I followed this tutorial for installing puppet master and puppet agent

https://coderwall.com/p/w6oxug/puppet-installation-on-ubuntu-12-04lts

Everything was working fine until I uninstall ruby, rvm, gem, bundler etc and made a fresh install of rvm, ruby update to 2.3.0.

I updated ruby to 2.3.0, updated gem, bundlet... But If I type puppet -V, I am getting the below error

sudo service puppet start

- Starting puppet agent                                                        /usr/bin/puppet:3:in `require': no such file to load -- puppet/util/command_line (LoadError)
      from /usr/bin/puppet:3

Gem Environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/user/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
     - /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
     - /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin
     - /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7/bin
     - /home/glassfish/bin
     - /usr/share/rvm/bin
     - /home/user/.rvm/bin
     - /home/user/.rvm/bin
```

**UPDATE 2:**

rvm -v
rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.1

gem -v
2.6.6

which ruby

/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby

which rails

/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rails

which gem

/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/gem

**UPDATE 3:**

foreman-installer

> File /var/log/foreman-installer/foreman-installer.log not writeable,
>   won't log anything to file!
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/kafo-0.9.4/lib/kafo/puppet_module.rb:69:in
>   `parse': No Puppet module parser is installed and no cache of the file
>   /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/foreman/manifests/init.pp is
>   available. Please check debug logs and install optional dependencies
>   for the parser. (Kafo::ParserError)

**UPDATE 4:**

Almost close to finishing installation:

I was using puppet 4 gem and that was causing UPDATE 3 errors. I downgraded puppet to version 3.7 and reinstalled highline and kafo gems

> gem install puppet -v 3.7
>
> gem install highline
>
> gem install kafo

Then tried

> foreman-installer
>
> Preparing installation Done
>
> Something went wrong! Check the log for ERROR-level output The full
>   log is at /var/log/foreman-installer/foreman-installer.log

In log, I can see these errors,

```
[ERROR 2016-08-30T08:13:17 main] Errors encountered during run:
[ERROR 2016-08-30T08:13:17 main]  Could not autoload puppet/parser/functions/add_progress: cannot load such file -- kafo/modules/kafo_configure/lib/kafo/puppet/report$
[ERROR 2016-08-30T08:13:17 main]  Could not autoload puppet/parser/functions/add_progress: cannot load such file -- kafo/modules/kafo_configure/lib/kafo/puppet/report$
[ERROR 2016-08-30T08:13:17 main]  Could not autoload puppet/parser/functions/add_progress: cannot load such file -- kafo/modules/kafo_configure/lib/kafo/puppet/report$

Could not autoload puppet/parser/functions/add_progress: cannot load such file -- kafo/modules/kafo_configure/lib/kafo/puppet/report_wrapper
```

**Current System Config**

```
rails -v
Rails 4.2.2

ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-linux]

gem -v
2.4.8

bundler -v
Bundler version 1.12.5

puppet -V
3.7.0
```

The above errors are for foreman-installer 1.4 and 1.7,

when I try 1.3 installer,

```
'uninitialized constant Kafo::KafoConfigure (NameError) '
```

**UPDATE 5:**
I can conclude one thing now....

```
It's all about finding the 
right puppet version, 
right kafo version, 
right foreman-installer, 
right ruby version and 
right gem version for ubuntu 12.04

IF anyone succeeded in installing foreman-installer 1.4 in ubuntu 12.04, please give me the version no for all above mentioned
```

Comment: The [guide](https://theforeman.org/manuals/1.12/quickstart_guide.html)  says, `This guide assumes that you have a newly installed operating system, on which the installer will setup Foreman, a Puppet master, and the Smart Proxy by default.` Do you have puppet installed?

Comment: Yes,
puppetmaster version 3.8.5
 puppet version 2.7.x. But everything broken now.... when I try to start service puppet start....

sudo service puppet start
 * Starting puppet agent                                                        /usr/bin/puppet:3:in `require': no such file to load -- puppet/util/command_line (LoadError)
        from /usr/bin/puppet:3
                                                                         [fail]

Comment: After installation,  puppet help command throwing this error
 puppet help
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'puppet' (>= 0) among 53 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44609/discussion-between-arun-and-anwar).

Comment: This is what I am getting When I try to do a fresh install of rvm

\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0   1350      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1769
100 22865  100 22865    0     0   112k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2915k
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/share/rvm': Permission denied

Comment: Hoooo finally solved by myself....

If you've run the rvm installer as root previously, remove /usr/local/rvm and /etc/rvmrc.

Comment: executing puppet -V throwing the below error:

puppet -V

/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'puppet' (>= 0) among 54 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:320:in `to_spec'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in

Comment: Anwar, check my update 3. I install puppet using gem install puppet, gem install highline and now foreman-installer is responding. Could you check update 3, it says something about puppet module parsers.... Do I have to install parser module ? if so how

Comment: Anwar, take a look at Update 4 if possible

Comment: Guys, Have a look at my UPDATE 5 and let me know

Comment: Anwar, I made it.... finally its working... :):):).
I will post the answer shortly

Comment: Great! Sad that I couldn't help. Hope the answer will be very helpful

Comment: no issues Anwar, no problem...thx for spending time to find the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my original question, In Ubuntu 12.04, Its all about meeting the right configuration for forman-installer, ruby, puppet, kafo, kafo_parsers, rails and gem.

This is the configuration that finally worked for me.

- foreman-installer 1.7
- ruby -v 2.1.1
- rails -v 4.2.2
- puppet -V 3.8.7
- kafo -v 0.9.4
- kafo_parsers -v 0.1.2
- gem  -v 2.6.6

When you are changing ruby version, make sure to update gems, install puppet gem and other required gems ( highline ) again

```
gem update --system
gem install highline
gem install puppet -v 3.8.7
```

Also, make sure you have the following foreman stuff updated. If you already have foreman old installer, You have to remove it first

```
sudo apt-get remove foreman-installer
```

Run this command "`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/foreman.list`" and update the file with this entry `deb http://deb.theforeman.org/ precise 1.7`
then run the below commands,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install foreman-installer
foreman-installer
```

This is the final configuration which finally worked for me.
Now I am struggling to change foreman port :)

Comment: Did using normal user installed rvm helped or needed system one?

Comment: Anwar, it's normal user installed rvm...